# Why won't my custom button class show up?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Android development. I wanted to make a custom ImageButton that toggles colors when you tap it for my project. I'd like to do it properly and for the button itself to keep track of its own state, so I extended the class and made ToggleImageButton below.

```
package com.ktpackages.elements.buttons

import android.annotation.TargetApi
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageButton
import com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.it
import com.ktpackages.tacosolo.R

class ToggleImageButton : ImageButton {
    private var toggle_state = true

    @JvmOverloads
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0) :
            super(context, null, defStyleAttr)
    {
        // Add onColor and offColor to attrs.
        setAttrs(attrs)
    }

    @TargetApi(21)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) :
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
        setAttrs(attrs)
    }

    private fun setAttrs(attrs: AttributeSet?) {
        attrs?.let {
            val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                it,
                R.styleable.custom_component_attributes, 0, 0
            )
            var offColor = resources.getText(
                a.getResourceId(
                    R.styleable
                        .custom_component_attributes_toggle_color_off,
                    R.color.design_default_color_primary
                )
            )
            var onColor = resources.getText(
                a.getResourceId(
                    R.styleable
                        .custom_component_attributes_toggle_color_off,
                    R.color.design_default_color_primary_dark
                )
            )

            a.recycle()
        }
    }

    var toggled: Boolean
        get() {
            return toggle_state
        }
        set(value) {
            if (toggle_state != value as Boolean) {
                toggle()
            }
        }

    fun toggle() {
        toggle_state = !toggle_state
        if (toggle_state) {
            setBackgroundColor(R.attr.toggle_color_on)
        } else {
            setBackgroundColor(R.attr.toggle_color_off)
        }
    }

    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.toggle_image_button, null, true)
    }
}
```

I followed several tutorials to get this far, but I'm getting a bit lost. From what I understand, the button must be inflated to render correctly in the Android Studio editor. So I added that code, using null for the ViewGroup, in the init. However, I get a NullPointerException when trying to access the button and the app crashes before loading the view. This did not happen when I simply had an ImageButton.

values/attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="custom_component_attributes">
        <attr name="toggle_color_on" format="color" />
        <attr name="toggle_color_off" format="color" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

layout/toggle_image_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageButton
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

Code that crashes:

```
    driveThruToggle.setOnClickListener {
        togglePins(driveThruToggle)
    }

    foodTruckToggle.setOnClickListener {
        togglePins(foodTruckToggle)
    }

    sitDownToggle.setOnClickListener {
        togglePins(sitDownToggle)
    }
```

layout.xml

```
<TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="67dp" android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/map" android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:weightSum="3">
        <com.ktpackages.elements.buttons.ToggleImageButton
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_car_128"
                app:toggle_color_off="@color/colorLightText"
                app:toggle_color_on="@color/colorBackground"
                android:id="@+id/driveThruToggle"
                android:background="@color/colorLightText" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <com.ktpackages.elements.buttons.ToggleImageButton
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chairs_128"
                app:toggle_color_off="@color/colorLightText"
                app:toggle_color_on="@color/colorBackground"
                android:id="@+id/sitDownToggle"
                android:background="@color/colorLightText" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <com.ktpackages.elements.buttons.ToggleImageButton
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_food_truck_128"
                app:toggle_color_off="@color/colorLightText"
                app:toggle_color_on="@color/colorBackground"
                android:id="@+id/foodTruckToggle"
                android:background="@color/colorLightText"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </TableRow>
```

I understand that toggle buttons already exist, but I'd like to learn how to do this.

Comment: You need to use your `toggle buttons` like this `<com.ktpackages.elements.buttons.ToggleImageButton`

Comment: Your class already is the `ImageButton`. You don't need to inflate anything internally. Aside from that, it's a little unclear what's crashing where.

Comment: The exception:    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ktpackages.tacosolo/com.ktpackages.tacosolo.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.ktpackages.elements.buttons.ToggleImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

On this line:

    driveThruToggle.setOnClickListener {

Comment: In addition, the button doesn't appear visually in the Android Studio editor.

Comment: Is that the layout, or part of the layout, that you're calling `setContentView()` with in `MapsActivity`? Or is it `<include>`d therein?

Comment: Yes, the line in question is two below setContentView

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that that doesn't work... I'm dumb.